# Python and XML Append for Feed RSS

Tags: python, xml, rss

I'm developing a simple Python script that generates an Feed RSS (XML).

But I can't append a new feed before the old, so as to have first rss always the latest news.

This is the code that I use to generate the initial XML file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from lxml import etree as ET

root = ET.Element("rss")
root.set("version", "2.0")

channel = ET.SubElement(root, "channel")

title = ET.SubElement(channel, "title")
title.text = "W3Schools Home Page"

link = ET.SubElement(channel, "link")
link.text = "http://www.w3schools.com"

description = ET.SubElement(channel, "description")
description.text = "Free web building tutorials"

item = ET.SubElement(channel, "item")

title = ET.SubElement(item, "title")
title.text = "RSS Tutorial"

link = ET.SubElement(item, "link")
link.text = "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_rss.asp"

description = ET.SubElement(item, "description")
description.text = "New RSS tutorial on W3Schools"

print ET.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)
#write to file:
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('feed.xml', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)
```

And this is the output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>W3Schools Home Page</title>
    <link>http://www.w3schools.com</link>
    <description>Free web building tutorials</description>
    <item>
      <title>RSS Tutorial</title>
      <link>http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_rss.asp</link>
      <description>New RSS tutorial on W3Schools</description>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

But if I can try add a new XML value with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from lxml import etree as ET
parser = ET.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = ET.parse("feed.xml", parser)
channel = tree.getroot()

item = ET.SubElement(channel, "item")

title = ET.SubElement(item, "title")
title.text = "Second Insert"
link = ET.SubElement(item, "link")
link.text = "http://second.test"
description = ET.SubElement(item, "description")
description.text = "description2"

channel[0].append(item)

print ET.tostring(channel, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)
tree = ET.ElementTree(channel)
tree.write("feed.xml", pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)
```

The result is this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>W3Schools Home Page</title>
    <link>http://www.w3schools.com</link>
    <description>Free web building tutorials</description>
    <item>
      <title>RSS Tutorial</title>
      <link>http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_rss.asp</link>
      <description>New RSS tutorial on W3Schools</description>
    </item>
    **<item>
        <title>Second Insert</title>
        <link>http://second.test</link>
        <description>description2</description>
    </item>**
  </channel>
</rss>
```

But I would like to get:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>W3Schools Home Page</title>
    <link>http://www.w3schools.com</link>
    <description>Free web building tutorials</description>
    **<item>
        <title>Second Insert</title>
        <link>http://second.test</link>
        <description>description2</description>
    </item>**
    <item>
      <title>RSS Tutorial</title>
      <link>http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_rss.asp</link>
      <description>New RSS tutorial on W3Schools</description>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

I made several attempts, but do not understand where I'm wrong.

Who can help me?

Thank you
Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add it after the *description* node, which you can do with [addnext](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#addnext):

```
channel.find(".//description").addnext(item)

print ET.tostring(channel, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)
```

Or previous to the first *item* which you can do with [addprevious](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#addprevious):

```
channel.find(".//item").addprevious(item)
```

Both will give you:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>W3Schools Home Page</title>
    <link>http://www.w3schools.com</link>
    <description>Free web building tutorials</description>
    <item>
      <title>Second Insert</title>
      <link>http://second.test</link>
      <description>description2</description>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>RSS Tutorial</title>
      <link>http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_rss.asp</link>
      <description>New RSS tutorial on W3Schools</description>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

`channel[0]` is the *channel* node  so appending to that is just going to add the new nodes at the end.